# Chrome re-downloading the same video after creating and destroy the <video> tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, dynamic

I am creating a video library. Whenever a user clicks on a thumbnail, a "video" element is dynamically appended to the page to let the user watch the video (I already tried to show/hide videos, but chrome loaded the page slowly, so I opted for the dynamic method). The problem is that if the user closes the video (destroying the "video" element) and clicks the same thumbnail (thus, re-creating the "video" element), Chrome spawns a new web request to download the video, but this request gets pending in the queue because the server allows only 1 request per time for each file and each IP (as the previous opening of the video caused the video to be downloaded). This doesn't happen in Firefox, where the browser instead of re-downloading the video, reuses the previously downloaded...
Is there a method to avoid this?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I am using to add:

```
$(this).find(".gallery > li").append("<video id=\"articlevideoobj\" class=\"videoProd\" preload=\"none\" controls=\"true\"><source src=\"" + video_src + ".mp4\" type=\"video/mp4\"><source src=\"" + video_src + ".ogg\" type=\"video/ogg\"</video>");
```

and this is the code I am using to remove it:

```
if (video_mode) {
    $('#articlevideoobj').remove();
}
```

Comment: will you give code that you are using to add "video" element?

Comment: read [this](http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2010/03/03/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio-2) and [this](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/#codecs)

Answer (score 1):

Before removing your video, call .stop() method on your video object and set src to '' :

```
 function stopVideo(elementId)
 {
   var video = document.getElementById(elementId);

   video.pause();
   video.src = '';
   video.parentNode.removeChild(video);
 }
```

Comment: I am trying this method: I'll let you know in a few minutes. By the way, there is no 'stop' method in the official <video> tag. You have to use 'pause'.

Comment: I mean pause, sorry for the typo